# Cannot install mySQL/maridDB on Debian 7 (Wheezy)

Tags: mysql, linux, debian, mariadb, raspbian-wheezy

Stackoverflow.
I am struggling for a past couple of days to install mySQL on my raspberry pi 2 :/
I am not Debian 7 (Wheezy) and there is no way I can change the distribution, have to work with that. So, i need to install MySQL version 5.5 or greater, or MariaDB and i have tried installing both, but none works.

 When installing MariaDB, following their [documentation](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=zol&distro=Debian&distro_release=wheezy--wheezy&version=10.0), when i get to the point

```
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
```

Am getting an error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.0 (= 10.0.32+maria-1~wheezy) but it is not installable
```

Tried googling and looking for similar cases, but can't find anything which would work.

 With mySQL things are even worst. Using their [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/) and MySQL APT Repository and [tutorials](http://www.debiantutorials.com/install-mysql-server-5-6-debian-7-8/) doing following steps:

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.8-1_all.deb
dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.8-1_all.deb (choosing mysql 5.6)
apt-get update
```

It shows error:

```
apt-get update
Hit http://mirror.zol.co.zw wheezy Release.gpg
Hit http://mirror.zol.co.zw wheezy Release
Hit http://mirror.zol.co.zw wheezy/main Sources
Hit http://mirror.zol.co.zw wheezy/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirror.zol.co.zw wheezy/main i386 Packages
Ign http://mirror.zol.co.zw wheezy/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://mirror.zol.co.zw wheezy/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy Release.gpg
Hit http://raspberrypi.collabora.com wheezy Release.gpg
Hit http://raspberrypi.collabora.com wheezy Release
Get:1 http://repo.mysql.com wheezy Release.gpg [173 B]
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy Release
Hit http://raspberrypi.collabora.com wheezy/rpi armhf Packages
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy/main armhf Packages
Get:2 http://repo.mysql.com wheezy Release [24.1 kB]
Get:3 http://repo.mysql.com wheezy/mysql-5.6 Sources [859 B]
Ign http://raspberrypi.collabora.com wheezy/rpi Translation-en_GB
Ign http://raspberrypi.collabora.com wheezy/rpi Translation-en
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy/main Translation-en
Fetched 25.2 kB in 5s (4,900 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/dists/wheezy/Release  Unable                                                            to find expected entry 'mysql-apt-config/binary-armhf/Packages' in Release file                                                            (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used                                                            instead.
```

And if i try:

```
apt-get install mysql-community-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql-community-server
```

Please help, any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any package in official debian repo in the name `mysql-community-server`. I found `mysql-server` package instead.
https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/mysql-server.

So try this:

- Add official debian repo to your sources list (i.e. add `deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security wheezy/updates main` to the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`)
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

Comment: Oh, it shows the same error...sudo apt-get install mysql-server
...
E: Unable to locate package mysql-server

Comment: Try following this guide step-by-step: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/

Comment: Or simply try: `sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Ambady Anand S, that's the exact instruction i was going through and am receiving "W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/dists/wheezy/Release  Unable".                                          And sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5 still shows " Couldn't find any package by regex 'mysql-server-5.5'"

Comment: Okay, try adding official debian repo to your sources list.  i.e. add `deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security wheezy/updates main` to the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`, then run `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5`. I hope that should work.

Comment: Thank you, Ambady, the installation has started, but i have got an error at the end [screenshoot](https://i.imgur.com/aypingh.png). i suppose the package did not get installed properly.

Comment: Oh, try `sudo apt-get -f install` then.

Comment: I just noted the permission denied error in the screenshot, so try this first `sudo mount -o remount,exec /tmp` and run the install command again.

Comment: Shut, still not... The same error  as on screen shoot. I have also noticed that it argues that: WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  mysql-common libmysqlclient18 libdbd-mysql-perl mysql-client-5.5 mysql-server-5.5
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
  could that be a problem? I have tried googling and trying different solution for verification, but no luck for now

Comment: Tried:  purging, sudo mount -o remount,exec /tmp, sudo apt-get -f install mysql-server-5.5... still the same error [new screenshoot](https://i.imgur.com/TIZKS1n.png)

Comment: I think it's better to start a new thread on this. You may also check similar issues like this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/457923/why-did-installation-of-mysql-5-6-on-ubuntu-14-04-fail?noredirect=1&lq=1